# What does 母を恋はずや mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

What is the meaning of 母を恋はずや in the film title?

Edit: the meaning of "恋う" according to the dictionary is "romantic love" as in "koi suru". E.g. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E6%81%8B%E3%81%86/m1u/ says "特定の異性に心ひかれて、その人を思い慕う。また、特別な人物や場所などを強く慕う。恋する。" So my query is partly about the grammar but also why it is 母を恋する. I can't believe it is some kind of incestuous relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dono already explained the grammar.  I will try to explain why 母を恋う does not describe an incestuous relationship.

Although the meanings of 恋う and 恋する have some overlap, 恋う is broader and it does not necessarily refer to a romantic emotion, unlike 恋する or 恋をする.  Daijirin is clearer on this:

[恋う](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E6%81%8B%E3%81%86):

> 1 (動ワ五［ハ四］)
>
> 思い慕う。愛する。懐かしく思う。
>
> > 母を―・う
> >     故郷を―・う気持ちがつのる
> >     妻―・ふ鹿の音〔出典： 松の葉〕
>
> 2 (動ハ上二)
>
> ［1］ 人、特に異性を恋する。ほれる。 …
>   ［2］ 慕わしく思う。 …
>   ［3］ （ある場所や物を）懐かしく思う。 …

[恋する](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E6%81%8B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B):

> 男女の間で、相手に愛情を寄せる。異性を愛する。
>
> > ―・する乙女

By the way, in modern Japanese, verb 恋う is rare except in compound words such as 恋い慕う and 恋い焦がれる, and [恋]{こい}しく思う is more common.  恋しい as in 恋しく思う also has the broader meaning which is not necessarily related to a romantic emotion.

Answer (score 7):

- 母: mother
- を: grammar, marks a direct object
- 恋はず: the verb 恋ふ in classical spelling. In modern Japanese, this is 恋う. (kop-u > koɸ-u > ko[w]-u > ko-u). Conjugated to こは (modern こわ) so that the negative suffix -zu can attach. "not love"
- や: grammar, interrogative particle asking a question. Often rhetorical.

Should one not love a mother? (=Yes, one should love a mother.)

Comment: It does not contain the meaning of “should.”

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito How are you interpreting "should"? There is no べき of course, but there are other meanings. In asking a rhetorical question (such as ～ないだろうか), I think it is appropriate as a translation. It could be changed to "Does one not love a mother?", but this sounds odd. Or "Is one not to love a mother?" which is better, but then you could say that the passive meaning is not included either. Translation is always a delicate balance and more than just literal word-by-word.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: The name of the movie in English is "A Mother Should Be Loved" [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mother_Should_be_Loved).

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito I have not seen the movie, but I note that it is given the English title "A Mother Should be Loved": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mother_Should_be_Loved . Apparently others thought "should" is appropriate, too.

Comment: A little question, on wikipedia, the romanization is "Haha o kowazuya". Why is the は is pronounced as わ in kowazuya (according to wikipedia)?

Comment: @xTCx Did you read the explanation above for 恋ふ? It is the classical spelling for 恋う. The negative form is こは (modern こわ) + -zu. Even if you write it as こは, it is pronounced as kowa. Consider the verb 言う. The negative is 言わず (iWAzu). Why is there a "w" in there? Because it was historically 言ふ, which is 言はない in classical spelling. This is pronounced iWAnai. I gave the historical sound changes above.

Comment: Ah, now I see why you put “should” there.  I would not use “should” to translate “母を恋はずや” or “母が恋しくないのか” (a rough equivalent in modern Japanese) but I understand that it is a possible translation.  It might be useful to add that explanation to the answer.

Comment: I think it might be more literally translated as "Is one's mother loved?" It doesn't explicitly say "should", but I think culturally (both English and Japanese) there's an assumption of "should" because... well, it's your mom, and I don't know of any culture that doesn't assume a mother should be loved.

Comment: @DaveMG Note though that with that translation you have changed the subject and made the verb passive, both of which are not in the Japanese. Translation is tough and you cannot please everyone, but it is missing the point. All that needs to be known for this question is in the four bullet points. From there, we can all make our own translations.

Comment: Dono, good point that I accidentally made it passive. However, don't get defensive about your answer. One answer with 4 points is not the be all and end all. The point of Stack Exchange is collaboration. Providing suggestions and alternate viewpoints is additional information that can be helpful to the original poster and any other interested party.

Comment: Dono... wait... isn't your translation, "Should one not love a mother?" also passive? Or at least, just as passive as mine?

Comment: @DaveMG I think you misunderstood what I meant by "four bullet points". These bullet points are not referring to the (at the time) four upvotes that I received, but to each of the four definitions in my answer that are prefixed with a ・. As for your question, I do not think that "Should one not love a mother" is passive. Change it to a non-question statement: One should love a mother. One is the subject, mother is a direct object, and love is a normal verb. The passive is "(to be) loved", which of course changes the subject from "one" to "(a) mother".

Comment: Dono, I know you were referring to the four bullet points *in* your answer (*not* the upvotes). That is what I was referring to as well. My point is that person's information does not preclude or invalidate other people's information. Your four points are very helpful. So are all the comments and discussion that everyone else has made on your answer, providing additional notes.

Comment: Dono (separating out comments by topic), I can see how my translation is passive, but is it not true that the original Japanese does not have a specific subject? It just says "mother/not loved/?". It doesn't say *who* is not doing the loving - you, me, a third person... So the original Japanese is not passive, but it doesn't specify the subject either, so wouldn't that leave it open to be translated as passive because we don't really do the non-passive-but-no-subject thing in English?

Comment: @DaveMG Of course the subject is not included. This is quite natural in Japanese, but English requires a specified subject. That is where the dummy "one" comes in. He/she/it/they are also possible, but I cannot say which is appropriate. "one" at least could be male or female. This is the appeal of passive: the direct object (mother) gets promoted to subject and there is no grammatical need to say "by who" the loving is being done. But in the Japanese, there is a subject--even if not specified--and the verb is non-passive. Hence the translation.

Comment: @Dono - Yes I've read it, and that's what got my confused in the first place. I thought こは was an old writing style and it grew to be わ... but from what I understand now, it was always わ, just written differently - am I right?